react- Assign jsx elements in sequence with input from array elements
I am trying to assign jsx elements sequentially in a component. this sequence should be based off of array elements of an input. let me elaborate on what i mean.
`let input = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat']`

Above is the input array and the sequence of how i want my jsx elements, jsx elements are below
```
let apple = (<div>Apple as first element</div>)
let ball = (<div>Ball as second element</div>)
let cat = (<div>Cat as third element</div>)

return (
    <>
      {input[0]}
      {input[1]}
      {input[2]}
   </>
)```

`
If i do the following shown above, jsx elements doesnot gets diplayed but if i do below code, jsx elements show fine.
```return (
    <>
      {apple}
      {ball}
      {cat}
   </>
)```

can someone let me know how to get the first scenario working.

const elements = {
  apple: <div>Apple as first element</div>,
  ball: <div>Ball as second element</div>,
  cat: <div>Cat as third element</div>
}

return (
  <>
    {input.map(val => elements[val])}
  </>
)

Or:
return (
  <>
    {input.map(val => {
      if (val === 'apple') {
        return <div>Apple as first element</div>
      } else if (val === 'ball') {
        return <div>Ball as second element</div>
      } else if (val === 'cat') {
        return <div>Cat as third element</div>
      }
    })}
  </>
)

